# How to add onclick event on the button on Woocommerce website?

Tags: woocommerce

I can't find file which is responsible for the red button on the page:
http://joyohboy.com/product/raising/

What is the right template in woocommerce for that? 
I'm using Hustle theme and woocommerce v. 2.2.10

Comment: Do you need the CSS file ? Or just the template name ? You can just refer to the page-sources to figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

The referred page also specifies Hustle theme.

You should refer to below for the CSS customisations,

http://www.themelocation.com/how-to-change-the-color-of-woocommerce-buttons/

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/